# error C2039: 'session' : is not a member of 'pjsua_call'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, pjsip

I am trying to make a dll of pjsip .

all is going well but when i am building the project after include pjsipDll i am facing this error :

error C2039: 'session' : is not a member of 'pjsua_call' . Well this is comming through pjsipDll.cpp in this line:

```
if(pjsua_var.calls[call_id].session == NULL)
```

After looking in output tab it is showing me to see the declaration of pjsua_call in pjsua_internal.h. In it in the struct declaration of pjsua_call the session is not defined. So please tell me how i resolve this error??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right, `.session` is not a member of `psjua_call`. Why do you think there should be a `session` member?